# Android: handle onItemClick() in listView-based app

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I'm working on a listView-based app: you have a main menu, when you click an item, a new activity starts with another menu; when you click again, a new activity starts with the content you selected. Since I've quite a lot of menu items, I've to create a listener which handles all possible cases, so I've something similar:

```
    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listAdapter, View v, int position, long id) {              
       String text = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
       //main menu
       if (text.equals(K.getStringById(K.ID_MAIN_THEORY))) {
          ...
       } else if (text.equals(K.getStringById(K.ID_MAIN_EXERCISE))) {
          ...
       }
       else if (text.equals(K.getStringById(K.ID_MAIN_TABLES))) {
          ...
       }
       //here other menus' items: lots of items
       ...
       //back item
       else if (text.equals(K.getStringById(K.ID_BACK))) {
          activity.finish();
       }

       Intent i = new Intent(...);
       startActivity(i);
    }
* K is a class that holds ids' references
```

There's a way I can avoid hard-coding listener behavior?

** PS: the lists' TextViews don't render properly: text appears light grey, not black! O.o

Comment: Seems to me that you shouldn't be using a ListView for this. This sounds more like just linear layouts inside scroll views with buttons you can tap.

Answer (score 0):

It's more useful to use the position rather than the view to switch the action of the click event. Your ListView should be populated from some sort of List, therefore when the onClick fires, giving you the position, you can reference that position in the List to know what was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on item and in result it goes to another activity, for example if you have three item and when you click on item A it will redirect you to activity A and if B then to B and so on,

```
   lstview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()  
     {
       private String input;
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> v, View arg1, int index,long arg3)
          {
            if(index==1)
               {
                 Intent intnt=new Intent(v.getContext(),A.class);     
                 startActivity(intnt);
                }       
            else if (index==2)
           {
              Intent intnt=new Intent(v.getContext(),B.class);     
                 startActivity(intnt);
                }       
              else
                 {
                   Intent intnt=new Intent(v.getContext(),C.class);     
                 startActivity(intnt);
                }       
           }
     }
```

Here in this case you are going to different activities on selection the items in a list view, put your comments for further query.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way: I think it's pretty good.

```
//This in K class, where MAPPED_HIERARCHY is a static field
static void activity(android.app.Activity a) {
    MAPPED_HIERARCHY = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    MAPPED_HIERARCHY.put(a.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), K.array2list(a.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_main)));
    MAPPED_HIERARCHY.put(a.getResources().getString(R.string.main_theory), K.array2list(a.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_theory)));
    MAPPED_HIERARCHY.put(a.getResources().getString(R.string.main_exercise), K.array2list(a.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_exercise)));
    ....
}
static ArrayList<String> getArrayListByString(String string) {
    ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(MAPPED_HIERARCHY.get(string).size());
    for (String s : MAPPED_HIERARCHY.get(string))
        copy.add(s);
    return copy; //defensive copy
}
//This in my listener class
@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listAdapter, View v, int position, long id) {          
        String text = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
        ArrayList<String> params = K.getArrayListByString(text);
        Intent i = new Intent(...);
        i.putExtra("params", params);
        activity.startActivity(i);
    }
```

I have a map which links an arraylist containing the menu items with the string wihich causes the menu to be displayed; on the click event, I simply retrieve the arraylist according with the selected item's text.